# Unable to adjust CSS for headers in the HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I'm new to HTML and I'm trying to run JavaScript with CSS. Everything is working fine except the table CSS in my code.

I'm unable to adjust the headers & table data spacing(padding) issues. Currently, there is a big spacing difference between headers and table data. I'm attaching my current output Please guide where to handle this situation.

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var dealPlan = document.getElementById("Deal_Type__c");
  var dealdetail = document.getElementById("data-table");
  var dealYear1 = document.getElementById("year-1-data");
  var dealYear2 = document.getElementById("year-2-data");
  var dealYear3 = document.getElementById("year-3-data");
  if (dealPlan.value === "") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "1 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "block";
    dealYear1.style.display = "block";
    dealYear2.style.display = "none";
    dealYear3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "2 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "block";
    dealYear1.style.display = "block";
    dealYear2.style.display = "block";
    dealYear3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "3 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "block";
    dealYear1.style.display = "block";
    dealYear2.style.display = "block";
    dealYear3.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      Deal Type:
      <select id="Deal_Type__c" onchange="ShowHideDiv()" name="Deal_Type__c" title="Deal Type">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <option value="1 Year">1 Year</option>
        <option value="2 Year">2 Year</option>
        <option value="3 Year">3 Year</option>
      </select><br>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <div id="data-table" style="display:none;">
      <table id="html-data-table">
        <tr>
          <th>YEARS</th>
          <th>#Applications</th>
          <th>#Users</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-1-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 1</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_1__c" name="Applications_Year_1__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_1__c" name="Users_Year_1__c" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-2-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 2</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_2__c" name="Applications_Year_2__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_2__c" name="Users_Year_2__c" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-3-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 3</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_3__c" name="Applications_Year_3__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_3__c" name="Users_Year_3__c" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to be more clear. "Unable to adjust" doesn't tell us anything about your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this is happening?

This is happening because you have used `display: block;` and [`block` is not a valid display form for `<tr>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display).

## How to fix it?

Use [`display: revert;`](https://www.google.com/search?q=display%20revert&oq=display%20revert&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i22i30l2j0i390l4.2799j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or `display: table-row;` instead. Where the first one reverts the display property to its original in the DOM and the second one is the original display property for a `<tr />` element.

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
  var dealPlan = document.getElementById("Deal_Type__c");
  var dealdetail = document.getElementById("data-table");
  var dealYear1 = document.getElementById("year-1-data");
  var dealYear2 = document.getElementById("year-2-data");
  var dealYear3 = document.getElementById("year-3-data");
  if (dealPlan.value === "") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "1 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear1.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear2.style.display = "none";
    dealYear3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "2 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear1.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear2.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (dealPlan.value === "3 Year") {
    dealdetail.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear1.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear2.style.display = "revert";
    dealYear3.style.display = "revert";
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      Deal Type:
      <select id="Deal_Type__c" onchange="ShowHideDiv()" name="Deal_Type__c" title="Deal Type">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <option value="1 Year">1 Year</option>
        <option value="2 Year">2 Year</option>
        <option value="3 Year">3 Year</option>
      </select><br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="data-table" style="display:none;">
      <table id="html-data-table">
        <tr>
          <th>YEARS</th>
          <th>#Applications</th>
          <th>#Users</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-1-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 1</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_1__c" name="Applications_Year_1__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_1__c" name="Users_Year_1__c" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-2-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 2</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_2__c" name="Applications_Year_2__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_2__c" name="Users_Year_2__c" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="year-3-data" style="display:none;">
          <td>Year 3</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Applications_Year_3__c" name="Applications_Year_3__c" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="Users_Year_3__c" name="Users_Year_3__c" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Didn't know about `revert`. I was about to propose to set it to `table-row` instead of `block`. Nice one.